# using asp.net required field validator with two check boxes

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, requiredfieldvalidator

i have two check boxes with male/female and i would like to add a required field validator for them so if none is checked then a custom error appears, i can already do this but with one control not two.

thanks

Comment: Any reason why a radio button wouldn't work? - The reason I ask is that the EXPECTED behavior of checkboxes are that you can check multiple.  Radio buttons are designed for exclusive sets.

Comment: do you have a submit button or something??  one option would be to validate the controls on page leave or something like that...

Comment: I agree that radio buttons are the more logical choice.  Unless, of course, your system must deal with hermaphrodites who have both male and female sex organs.

Comment: @Steve - While you are correct, the system that the OP was describing with only allowing one checkbox to be checked obviously precludes your scenario as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was instead of adding two separate `CheckBox`s ,I needed to  add a **`CheckBoxList`**:

[`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

and then use a normal `RequiredFieldValidator` on the `CheckBoxList`:

[`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the CustomValidator with a ClientValidationFunction

http://forums.asp.net/t/1402179.aspx

- or -

You'll need to write a custom control or use one that's already made:

-http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultiDependValidator.aspx